# Python - Mocking nested DB calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to write unit test for **some_func** function in **some_func.py** below. I do not want to connect to any database during this tests and I want to mock out any calls to DB.

Since the actual db calls are somewhat nested, i'm not able to get this to work. How do i patch any db interaction in this case?

db_module.py

```
import MySQLdb

from random_module.config.config_loader import config
from random_module.passwd_util import get_creds

class MySQLConn:

    _conn = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = self._get_rds_connection()

    def get_conn(self):
        return self._conn

    def _get_rds_connection(self):
        """
        Returns a conn object after establishing connection with the MySQL database

        :return: obj: conn
        """

        try:

            logger.info("Establishing connection with MySQL")

            username, password = get_creds(config['mysql_dev_creds'])

            connection = MySQLdb.connect(
                host=config['host'],
                user=username,
                passwd=password,
                db=config['db_name'],
                port=int(config['db_port']))

            connection.autocommit = True

        except Exception as err:
            logger.error("Unable to establish connection to MySQL")
            raise ConnectionAbortedError(err)

        if (connection):
            logger.info("Connection to MySQL successful")
            return connection
        else:
            return None

db_mysql = MySQLConn()
```

some_func.py

```
from random_module.utils.db_module import db_mysql

def some_func():

    try: 

        db_conn = db_mysql.get_conn()
        db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

        results = db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
        results = db_cursor.fetchall()

        result_set = []

        for row in results:

            result_set.insert(i, row['x'])
            result_set.insert(i, row['y'])

    except Exception:
        logger.error("some error")

    return result_set
```

dir struct -

```
src
├──pkg
|   ├── common
|      |___ some_func.py
|      |___ __init__.py
|       
|   ├── utils
|      |___ db_module.py
|      |___ __init__.py
|
| __init__.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock this line: `db_conn = db_mysql.get_conn()`

The return value of the get_conn method is what you're interested in.

```
from random_module.utils.db_module import db_mysql

@mock.patch.object(db_mysql, 'get_conn')
def test_some_func(self, mock_get):
    mock_conn = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_get.return_value = mock_conn
    mock_cursor = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_conn.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor

    expect = ...
    result = some_func()

    self.assertEqual(expect, result)
    self.assertTrue(mock_cursor.execute.called)
```

As you can see there is a lot of complexity setting up these mocks. That is because you are instantiating objects inside of your function. A better approach would be to refactor your code to inject the cursor because the cursor is the only thing relevant to this function. An even better approach would be to create a database fixture to test the function actually interacts with the database correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock `db_mysql` in `some_module.py` and then assert that the expected calls were made after `some_func()` executes.

```
from unittest TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from some_module import some_func

class SomeFuncTest(TestCase):

    @patch('some_module.db_mysql')
    def test_some_func(self, mock_db):
        result_set = some_func()

        mock_db.get_conn.assert_called_once_with()
        mock_cursor = mock_db.get_conn.return_value
        mock_cursor.assert_called_once_with()

        mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with("SELECT * FROM some_table")
        mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [
            {'x': 'foo1', 'y': 'bar1'},
            {'x': 'foo2', 'y': 'bar2'}
        ]
        mock_cursor.fetchall.assert_called_once_with()

        self.assertEqual(result_set, ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2'])
```

Comment: I edited the question as i have the some_func.py module and some_func method same. When i try to patch i'm doing @mock.patch('pkg.common.some_func.db_mysql'). But this is resulting in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'some_func'. I even have the __init__.py listed in the common directory.

Comment: The package module is called `__init__.py`. You have one of these in `pkg` and `common`?

Comment: Updated the dir structure. I have a  `__init__.py ` in every folder.

Comment: Do you have a `common.py` alongside your `common` package? It seems the patch is getting confused there somehow.

Comment: No I don't. Since db_mysql is getting instantiated in a different class, do you think that could be the culprit?

Comment: And the dot lookup does not seem to go beyond pkg.common. Its trying to look for attribute some_func under pkg.common although my patch is defined as  `@mock.patch('pkg.common.some_func.db_mysql')`

Comment: Perhaps try moving the `some_func.py` module around and adjusting the patch path accordingly to try and debug this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169606/discussion-between-naveen-and-will-keeling).